# send/receive OSC messages to Android with JavaOSC

Tags: java, android, osc, javaosc

I'm trying to write sample Android application that allows to send and receive OSC messages using JavaOSC library. In the example we are sending the current value of a simple Android seekBar with OSC message.

The LogCat says:

```
09-03 04:56:25.695: I/System.out(1235): can not send
```

Here is my sample code, unfortunately it does not work (it seems that i have an exception while trying to send message). Maybe someone knows what is it wrong here?

I'm totally new in Android dev., thank's for all advices...

```
 package com.remote.secondtest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;





public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    private SeekBar myBar;
    private TextView textProgress, textAction;
    public OSCPortOut sender = null;
    private OSCPortIn  receiver;
    public InetAddress targetIP;
    int port = 5001;
    protected int sliderValue;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myscreen);

        myBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        myBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);        
        textProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);
        textAction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewAction);

    } 

    public void setConnection(){
        try {
            targetIP = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.104");
            //targetIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();        }        

        try {
            sender = new OSCPortOut(targetIP, 4444); //------set up outgoing ------
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*try {                                     //------set up incoming-------
            receiver = new OSCPortIn(4444);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } */ 

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } 


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        textProgress.setText("The value is: " + progress);
        textAction.setText("changing");

        sliderValue = progress;
        sendMyOscMessage();
        //receiveMyOscMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        textAction.setText("starting to track touch");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
        textAction.setText("ended tracking touch");     

    }

    public void sendMyOscMessage(){
        Object args [] = new Object[2];
        args[0] = "Current_Value_is: ";
        args[1] = sliderValue;
        OSCMessage msg = new OSCMessage("/test_from_device", args);

        try {
            sender.send(msg);
            System.out.println("OSC message sent!");
            System.out.println(args[0].toString() + args[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("can not send");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /*public void receiveMyOscMessage(){
        OSCListener myListener = new OSCListener() {

            @Override
            public void acceptMessage(Date time, OSCMessage message) {

                System.out.println("myMessage_received!");              
                //Object [] args = message.getArguments();
                //String myTitle = args[0].toString();
                //int currentValue = (Integer)args[1];
            }
        }; 

        receiver.addListener("/test_to_device", myListener);
        receiver.startListening();

    }*/


}
```

UPD: the OSCMessage constructor was deprecated but after i modified it for a valid constructor there is no changes...

```
OSCMessage msg = new OSCMessage();
    msg.setAddress("192.168.0.104");
    msg.addArgument(args);
```

Between a lot of android errors log says:

> 09-03 07:56:00.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-03 07:56:00.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2408): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-03 07:56:00.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2408):     at com.remote.secondtest.MainActivity.sendMyOscMessage(MainActivity.java:132)
>   09-03 07:56:00.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2408):     at com.remote.secondtest.MainActivity.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:93)
>   09-03 07:56:00.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2408):     at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:91)

Comment: The error contains line numbers that don't fit the code you posted. Which version of JavaOSC are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need permissions to access Internet.

Since the line numbers don't match your errors i can't be sure but I'm guessing this is the most common error, leading to "can not send".